# Delete OpenLDAP log files

Tags: logging, openldap

The application I maintain is using LDAP for database, but the problem is, the log files (`log.XXX...XXX`) has grown too big (17Gb), and no one here (including me) has an idea how to remove them, because it seems I cannot just delete them.

The `slapd.conf` file contains (I only put the values I think are relevant):

```
checkpoint 1024 5
cachesize 10000
overlay syncprov
syncprov-checkpoint 1 1
syncprov-sessionlog 100
```

I tried to create a `DB_CONFIG` file, where the directory is set in the `slapd.conf`, containing

```
# In memory cache for log information (~2Gb)
set_lg_bsize 2097152

set_flags DB_LOG_AUTOREMOVE on
```

Then I restarted the LDAP server, but it does not seem to work (or maybe I just set the wrong parameters and flags...).

Does somebody have any idea how to clean the log files? And can someone tell me if something's wrong in my `DB_CONFIG` file?

Answer (score 2):

If you make any changes in the DB_CONFIG file (or the indexing parameters in `slapd.conf` or `slapd.d`) you have to run `slapindex` before restarting `slapd`.